# filter array of object using lodash or underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash, underscore.js

I have the following structure and this data is displaying as the list in (as in my given screenshot), here I want to add a filter, like say If I put "a" in my search box it should display all the names which has "a" and when I type the full name like "atewart Bower" it should only show the one list. So far I doing this

```
        const searchContact = newData.filter(d => { // here newData is my arr of objs                       
            let alphabet = d.alpha.toLowerCase();
            return alphabet.includes(this.state.searchUserName.toLowerCase())
        })
```

it is returning on the basis of "alpha" not "name" inside the users array. I was trying to use `Lodash` and `underscore.js`, but didn't find what I want to achieve there too.

I tried this code of `Lodash`

```
const dd = _.filter(newData, { users: [ { name: this.state.searchUserName } ]});
```

but it also return the array of object when I write the full name like when `this.state.searchUserName = atewart Bower`

```
[
    { 
      alpha: "a",
      users: [
        {
          id: "1",
          name: "atewart Bower"
        },
        {
          id: "1",
          name: "aatewart Bower"
        },
      ]
    },
    { 
      alpha: "b",
      users: [
        {
          id: "1",
          name: "btewart Bower"
        },
        {
          id: "1",
          name: "bbtewart Bower"
        },
      ]
    }
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is filtering on basis of alpha because inside the filter, we are using alpha value to check.

```js
let alphabet = d.alpha.toLowerCase();
return alphabet.includes(this.state.searchUserName.toLowerCase())
```

To check inside the users array, you can do something like this

```js
const getSearchedContacts = (newData, searchUserName) => {
    const searchResults = [];
    newData.forEach((item) => {
        const users = item.users.filter(user => user.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchUserName.toLowerCase()));
        if (users.length) searchResults.push({...item, users});
    });
    return searchResults;
};

getSearchedContacts(yourData, 'atewart Bower'); // Returns [{"alpha":"a","users":[{"id":"1","name":"atewart Bower"}]}]
```

Note: I'm using `startsWith` instead of `includes` because we want to return only one name when search string is for example "atewart Bower"

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what will happen If I type only "a"? does it work or do I have to type the full name 'atewart Bower' ?

Comment: Thanks it is working and introducing me for the new array method `startWith` but here I am getting only this object in array [{id: "1",name: "atewart Bower"}] and I want output like 
[
    { 
      alpha: "a",
      users: [
        {
          id: "1",
          name: "atewart Bower"
        },
      ]
   }
]

and how do we fix the casing issue, if someones name start with capital char then I also have to to type it in capital case

Comment: Hi @shashiverma, I have changed the function a bit to get the desired result. And also good catch about the casing of letters, I have added the ````toLowerCase```` function before checking ````startsWith```` to ensure check is case insensitive.